# XML-RPC C# and Python RPC Server

Tags: c#, python, xml-rpc

On my server, I'm using the standard example for Python (with an extra Hello World Method) and on the Client side I'm using the XML-RPC.NET Library in C#.
But everytime I run my client I get the exception that the method is not found. Any Ideas how fix that.

thanks!

Python:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("", 8000),
                            requestHandler=RequestHandler)
server.register_introspection_functions()

# Register pow() function; this will use the value of
# pow.__name__ as the name, which is just 'pow'.
server.register_function(pow)

# Register a function under a different name
def adder_function(x,y):
    return x + y
server.register_function(adder_function, 'add')

def HelloWorld():
        return "Hello Henrik"

server.register_function(HelloWorld,'HelloWorld')

# Register an instance; all the methods of the instance are
# published as XML-RPC methods (in this case, just 'div').
class MyFuncs:
    def div(self, x, y):
        return x // y

server.register_instance(MyFuncs())

# Run the server's main loop
server.serve_forever()
```

C#

```
namespace XMLRPC_Test
{
    [XmlRpcUrl("http://188.40.xxx.xxx:8000")]
    public interface HelloWorld : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod]
        String HelloWorld();
    }
    [XmlRpcUrl("http://188.40.xxx.xxx:8000")]
    public interface add : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod]
        int add(int x, int y);
    } 
    [XmlRpcUrl("http://188.40.xxx.xxx:8000")]
    public interface listMethods : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod("system.listMethods")]  
        String listMethods();
    } 

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            listMethods proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<listMethods>();
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.listMethods());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting the exception you get, including stacktrace, could possibly be helpful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it work if you change the declaration to this?

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://188.40.xxx.xxx:8000/RPC2")]
```

From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html):

> `SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler.rpc_paths`
>
> An attribute value that must be a tuple listing valid path portions of the URL for receiving XML-RPC requests. Requests posted to other paths will result in a 404 “no such page” HTTP error. If this tuple is empty, all paths will be considered valid. The default value is ('/', '/RPC2').