# XMLRPC c# client to python client - method does not exists

Tags: c#, python, xml-rpc, simplexmlrpcserver

I've searched the web and seen the following question: [XML-RPC C# and Python RPC Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583017/xml-rpc-c-and-python-rpc-server)

I'm trying for a while to do the same, but I fail. I get the exception "Method "HelloWorld" is not supported..."

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://192.168.0.xxx:8000/RPC2")]
public interface HelloWorld : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod]
    String HelloWorld();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HelloWorld proxy = CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<HelloWorld>();
        textBox1.Text = proxy.HelloWorld();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

And my Python server is:

```
class LGERequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

def HelloWorld():
    return "This is server..."

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("192.168.0.xxx", 8000),
                        requestHandler=LGERequestHandler)

server.register_introspection_functions()
server.register_function("HelloWorld", HelloWorld)
server.register_instance(self)

# Run the server's main loop
server.serve_forever()
```

The server is up and running, but I still get an exception.

Comment: That is not valid python, the dedents dont match the indents.  Please edit your answer to reflect the actual code you're having a problem with.  (hint: paste the code into the edit box, select the whole block, then click the `{}` button to get the indenting to show up correctly)

Comment: Looks like the C# client is not considering the method to be "HelloWorld".  Maybe if you register it as "HelloWorld.HelloWorld" instead, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

1. Syntax problem `server.register_function("HelloWorld", HelloWorld)` should be `server.register_function(HelloWorld, "HelloWorld")`.
2. This change also didn't work, so I changed the function name form `helloWorld` to `hello` and it worked(!)