# Secure and Short Server-Client Connection

Tags: c#, android, python, mysql, server

I am working on a very simple game for Android that showcases writing an android app for nearly nothing.

The game will be made with Unity so it will be written in c#. I was hoping to write the server software in Python because I need to work on my familiarity with the language and I'd like it to run on a raspberry pi (Mostly for proof of concept).

The server only has to worry about a single table, in a single database. This will hold a "High Score" table in MYSQL.

That's the background, now to my question. What is a secure and easy way of getting data to the server from the app and vice-versa? I was looking at [XML based RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674769/xml-rpc-call-python-functions-from-c-sharp) but wanted to see if there was an easier method of doing it. The app just needs to pass the score, initials, and a hash for validation. The server just needs to be able to send the table back.

It doesn't have to be wicked secure since I'm not storing anything essential but would like to prevent false entries, which is why I have the hash to validate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad general question, but here is how I am thinking about it. Having done some Unity3d work in the past, I will make an attempt.

First off, I would not use MySQL, rather I would use PostgreSQL or maybe a no-sql database like Couchbase. Couchbase and other no-sql databases are popular among game developers because they are more scalable and have flexible schemas- compared with a traditional Rdbms. This part is of course just my opinion.

Your idea of using a hash (SHA is recommended) to prevent basic forgeries, is a good approach, for a minimal level of security. Just do not forget to add some secret words to the hash and keep the secrets hidden and out of memory- if possible. The secret would also need to known by the server, to be able to replicate the hash code.

On the server side, going with Python is always a good idea- imho. I would use Flask or other some minimal web framework, and start building a RESTful api that you can just hit with HTTP requests from the Unity3d client.

The data sent back and forth between the client would just be JSON (it's more compact than XML), and there are several JSON libraries available for Unity3d- just be sure to get one specifically for Unity, because some general C# libraries might fail in Unity if they depend on Reflection, and depending on the target platform as well.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking SHA1 or MD5. Is PostgreSQL pretty easy to pickup if you know MYSQL and MSSQL? I've never used anything but those two but I'm down to learn if it has a use case. Sorry for broad question, I wanted to see how other people would handle this situation without putting many constraints on it.

Comment: For an app like you describe, MySQL or PostgreSQL would be more than sufficient. Postgres is just my fave. They are both open source relational databases. From what I have read using SHA-2 or newer would be more secure than SHA1, but I am no crypto expert!

Comment: SHA2 would definitely be more secure as it give a longer hash. I'll probably go with that. (I've just used SHA1 in unity before for save file checks so that's why I said it). Because the hash would be constantly changing though, it would be worthless by the time it was decrypted. I may test though with hashcat. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I favor postgres over mysql as well, though for something simple like this I would lean towards nosql. Redis is a great nosql database that is fast and relatively easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

A REST api built using the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework is simple and easy to implement.

For strong security you can use HTTPS when you deploy it. You can create SSL certificates to include with your game code and have your application server require a client certificate in order for the connection to be made. This would prevent unauthenticated clients from being able to even connect to your server.

Comment: Buying/Generating an SSL wouldn't be a bad idea but its not going to send any data that needs protection. It would prevent inline modification but might not be worth the effort since these will be running on Android.

Comment: A hash with a shared secret like @alex-g-rice suggests would be much easier to implement. I would stay away from md5 too - it's considered broken now. SHA-2 is much more secure.

Comment: Yeah that was the original idea. I know how broken MD5 and SHA1, I've just used them in unity before but probably best as you say to use SHA2 or a stronger crypto.